# Laravel 5.4, What is the best session driver for an e-commerce website

Tags: laravel, session, redis, memcached

Hello i need help to decide what the best session driver i must use in my e-commerce website. Redis? Memcached? file driver? or other?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**It depends on your setup**

If you choose the `file session driver`, your `session data` will be saved in the app/storage/sessions folder on the `server`.

If you choose the `database` session driver, you can use the DB to keep sessions.

Otherwise, you can store the data (encrypted) in the user cookies.

**Why use file driver:-**

The advantage of using the `file driver` could be that `mySQL/SQL` server load whereas file
access should be faster.

**Why use database driver:-**

If your site isn't that big (couple hundreds unique a day). It also provides you with easy access to all the users logged in from a time period so you can track stuff.

**Why use Redis / Memcached driver:-**

`Redis & Memcached` driver both provide high reading speed. so when you need to frequently access data, this is your best choice & also if your site is very big & the data read/write frequency is high.

So choose any of them according to your need.

Comment: Thank you. I will choose redis in all cases

Comment: Great! Simple and exact explanation

Comment: One important advantage of using a database driver is the ability to maintain multiple applications that utilize a single connection string to access session data. This eliminates the need to synchronize session files between application servers.